# override default c++ class template in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I create a new C++ class in visual studio 2010, it generates a class with some template code. How can I modify this template to suit my own needs ?

Comment: I don't have a problem with it generating default code for me. I want to modify the default code that it generates.

Comment: Have you checked this folder: Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\Generic\Class

Answer (score 3):

One problem with finding info about this is most of information about creating templates is for .NET and the process is different for Visual C++.   Also the answer is probably not what you want to hear because it involves editing javascript code rather than just editing some template file.  It's possible that you can create a brand new wizard that uses a template file, but this is one way to modify the default template without doing that.  Modifying the wizard code involves editing a javascript file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\Generic\Class\Scripts\1033\default.js

The javascript uses the [CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t41260xs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to manipulate (or generate, in this case) source code.  Inside that file there is an `OnFinish` function which you can use to modify the class details that are output.  You will see a line like this in the file:

```
var newclass = oCM.AddClass(strClassName,
strHeader, vsCMAddPositionEnd, "", "", vsCMAccessDefault);
```

to add a new function you would do something like:

```
newclass.AddFunction("MyFunction", vsCMFunctionFunction,
vsCMTypeRefVoid, vsCMAddPositionEnd, vsCMAccessPublic, strImpl);
```

You can read about it here:

[Inside Visual C++ Wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730846%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Reference Documentation:

[Designing a Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xz4cw2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The default templates are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcprojectitems`. Change as appropriate for x86-vs-x64 and VS version.

Comment: i see a "newc++file.cpp/h" in that directory. But, they're both empty. Size is 0KB. Do I need to modify the wizard files ? I even opened "addmc++componentclass.vsz" to see if there is something i can edit there, but it had nothing the likes of the template code that is generated.

Comment: @Roger can you be a little more explicit about what you'd need to modify to modify the class generated by the "Generic C++ Class Wizard" when you choose "Add Class" menu option?

Comment: The stuff in `vcprojectitems` controls what you see (and what is generated) from **Project / Add New Item**. The `Add Class` C++ wizard is defined in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\Generic\Class\Scripts\1033\default.js`, and it uses `EnvDTE.CodeModel` to do the actual code generation. I can't see a way to replace this functionality. You could always write a simple VS extension to replace this menu item with your own, though...

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand correctly)

I don't think you can modify the code that is auto-generated by a wizard, for example when adding a new class.

You could maybe code a new wizard ?
M.

Answer (score 0):

Checked in MVS 2008...

File: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\Generic\Class\Scripts\1033\default.js

Added code (after creating default ctor & dtor in the default.js)

```
    var oCopyCtor = newclass.AddFunction(strClassName+"(const "+strClassName+"& refObj)", vsCMFunctionConstructor, "", vsCMAddPositionEnd, vsCMAccessPrivate, strImpl);
    var oAssignmentOperator = newclass.AddFunction("operator=(const "+strClassName+"& rhs)", vsCMFunctionOperator, strClassName+"&", vsCMAddPositionEnd, vsCMAccessPrivate, strImpl);

    oAssignmentOperator.BodyText = "if(&rhs == this) { return *this; }\n//TODO: real assignment here...\nreturn *this;\n"
```

But I still can't figure out how to turn off implementation in *.cpp (x.BodyText = ""; doesn't help), and omitting strImpl parameter puts the implementation in the *.h file