# Change default class item template provided by AddClass Wizard in vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a class template that would account for the precompiled header if present (which happens with the default add class wizard), but I'd like to expand the barebone template provided by the wizard with a constructor, (possibly virtual) destructor and a bunch of private and public sections. I have read the microsoft pages talking about item templates, but I cannot seem to find the functionality that would allow me to account for the precompiled header.

Is there a way (even a hacky one) of modifying the add class wizard without having to create a vs extension from scrap?

Something similar seems to be possible with C# templates as can be seen from various posts advising to modify Class.cs in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class`, unfortunately, I cannot find the C++ equivalent.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is somewhat difficult：
[override default c++ class template in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044099/override-default-c-class-template-in-visual-studio-2010)

modify item template may be easier:

1.Add class through class wizard and code

```
#pragma once
class Myclass
{
public:
    Myclass();
    ~Myclass();
protected:
    int test();

private :
};
```

2. Tool bar: Project-> Export Template->Item template
3. Then you can add custom item(may need to restart Visual Studio)

E.g.

[image]

```
#pragma once
class hello
{
public:
    hello();
    ~hello();
protected:
    int test();

private :
};
```

Comment: Hi, @Eris May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

Comment: I hardcoded everything in by exporting the template like you suggested. I had to change the `<TemplateContent>` by adding `<ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cpp" ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cpp</ProjectItem>` since it let me only select a single file, I chose the header. The thing i wanted to achieve was in the post you pointed to (vs2017 directory pointed in the [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896517/16614732) seems to be `Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\ ` ) I'll write an update once I find the correct file